# disable downloading of the PHP files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, download

In my server I want to show the list of the php files available in a folder. But I don't want to let my users to copy or save them, just be able to open the PHP file.

Comment: I think what you are asking for here is to show a listing of PHP files, and when users click on them, they execute on your web server? Instead of having those PHP files "downloaded". It sounds like you have a configuration error on your server where the PHP files aren't being processed through the PHP interpreter? Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can list all files in a specific directory using `glob()`.

```
//here, I will grab all PHP file names, and throw them into a assoc array:
$fileArr = glob('path/*.php');

foreach($fileArr as $val)
{

echo $val."<br>";

}

//now you have all your file names listed
```

To prevent users making `http` requests to them, you use `htaccess`:

Make a .`htaccess` file in the directory your files are sitting in and paste this into it:

`deny from all`

Now, no one can make `http` requests to files in that directory.

Why you want to do this though, is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you mean "open" as in execute, you should realize that as far as the web server is concerned, it is utterly impossible to figure out a user's intent. It's not as if the browser will fetch a file and say "this is for saving" and "this is for executing".

This means that one way or another, the user HAS to download the file, regardless of what they're going to end up using the file for.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if user opens a PHP file using his computer, the user already has the file and he/she of course can copy/save it.

Comment: You are partly right. The browser cache will have a copy of the output the PHP file generates, but not the actual source code.